# Unique determination of displacement gradients in structural physics?

Tags: elasticity, stress-strain, displacement, structure-formation

I am working on a 2-D planar problem in the x-y direction, dealing with stresses, strain, displacements. Under the linear elastic relation and after substitution I can write the following:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_{xx} & \sigma_{xy} \\
    \sigma_{xy} & \sigma_{yy}
\end{bmatrix} = \mu
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
 + \mu
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} &  \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
 + \lambda\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} & 0\\
 0 &  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

I need to obtain the unknowns, which are the 4 displacement gradients
$$
\frac{du}{dx}; \frac{du}{dy}; \frac{dv}{dx}; \frac{dv}{dy}
$$

However, since the stress matrix is symmetrical, I only have 3 knowns. In structural problems, where does this 4th condition come from?

Comment: What is the specific physical problem you're solving?

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply "Compatibility" conditions to the strain field. For small deformations, these conditions ensure that the displacement gradient components that you are looking for result from the gradient of a true displacement field. For this to be true, the "curl of the curl of strain" must disappear everywhere.

$$
\nabla \times (\nabla \times \epsilon) = \mathbf{0}
$$
where $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}\left(\nabla \mathbf{u} + (\nabla \mathbf{u})^T\right)$ is the infinitesimal strain tensor.

For your two-dimensional problem, this condition takes the form:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 \epsilon_{11}}{\partial x_1^2} - 2\frac{\partial^2 \epsilon_{12}}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} + \frac{\partial^2 \epsilon_{22}}{\partial x_2^2} = 0
\end{align*}

This is the last equation that you need in order to solve for the components of the displacement gradient.

As a point of interest, it is usually easier to solve for the actual displacement field and to post-process this field for the stresses and strains. This is the procedure used in finite element software packages, and indeed in most analytical approaches as well. I'd recommend that you look up "variational methods" for elasticity

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_(mechanics)